# Authentication object not found thrown by DispatcherServlet before @Preauthorize spring security annotation is applied

Tags: spring, spring-security

When i am trying to use @PreAuthorize("@accessControl.hasActivity('abc')") on spring controller method i am getting Authentication object was not found in security context.
After debugging found that DispactcherServlet is throwing this exception.

i have set  SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL);
when i first create Authentication object and set in security context

Also tried with     SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL); but no luck still it does not work.

I am not able to understand why spring is servlet is throwing this exception

Comment: Post full exception + stack trace.

Comment: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Comment: @holmis83 do you think it is thread issue ?

Comment: According javadoc, setStrategyName must only be set once per JVM.

Comment: I have set it only once when i first create the authentication object and set it in security context

Comment: How do you authenticate? Can you verify that authentication is performed?

Comment: I have a spring interceptor(extending HandlerInterceptor) in which when first request comes i create an authentication object as below )

Comment: String userName = httpServletRequest.getSession().getId();
String password = httpServletRequest.getSession().getId();
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
AbstractAuthenticationToken abstractAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password, authorities);
UserAccessDetail userAccessDetail = new UserAccessDetail();
userAccessDetail.setLoggedInUserVO(loggedInUserDetails);
abstractAuthenticationToken.setDetails(userAccessDetail);
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL);

Comment: It is failing only in case if i am trying to use @PreAuthorize on any controller method then dispatcher servlet is throwing exception org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundExc‌​eption: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Comment: @holmis83 do you require any more detail

Answer (score 1):

First, doing authentication in a Spring MVC interceptor is odd. Consider using a filter before DispatcherServlet. There is a lot of documented examples.

Secondly, `SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName` re-initializes the strategy and possibly makes all previously authentications inaccessible so you must only call it once (if any time), before any authentication is made.

Thirdly, if you want to set the current authentication to be used by @PreAuthorize and are sure what you are doing, use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(anAuthentication);`. In most cases, there is a suitable filter in the API that already does this for you.